# Effects of out of phase angle ac voltage between two power grids

Tags: power

I am currently learning the basic of pmu and its effect in ensuring the reliability of power transmission. I have seen that to ensure grid reliability, synchronisation of 31.78us is needed to keep tve within 1%. However, I do not understand what is the effect of such synchronisation. What is the effect of out of phase angle power grid? How will it affect the reliability of power transmission system? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please capitalise your acronyms and explain what they mean to those of us unfamiliar with them. If you have links to reference material ("*I have seen that ...*") then add them in.

Answer (score 1):

What happens whenever you connect any two voltage sources in parallel that don't have the same voltage at the same time? A massive current flows, limited only by the parasitic resistance of the wiring and the sources themselves.

In synchronous machines such as the alternators used to produce AC power, this current creates a large torque that effectively forces the phase error to zero. After that, it is the external torque on the shaft that determines whether the machine is a net producer or net consumer of grid power.

Comment: How does it actually increase the current flow? Can you please elaborate

Comment: Do you understand [Ohm's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law)? [Kirchhoff's Voltage Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws)? Without a basic understanding of these concepts, there isn't much I can do.

Comment: Okay may I ask more specific question is it because of the impedance mismatch between two source due to phase angle difference?